# Django: Querying Multiple Foreign Keys

Tags: python, django, orm, models

First off, I'm sure this is a simple question. I'm just getting started with Django and as all beginners do, I thought I'd build a simple blog.

I have a simple data model, a Post model that contains with a link to a user via a FK.

**models.py**

```
class Post(TimeStampedActivate):
    """
    A blog post
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Is the blog post active?')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='post_user')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I then want a page that lists all of the Posts alongside the username of the person who created the post. My current view looks like this:

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(active=True)   
    user = User.objects.get(id=1)
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'posts': posts, 'user': user})
```

**My template**
At present this just displays the users name that matches an ID of 1.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h2><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <p>{{ post.excerpt|truncatewords:30 }}</p>
    <p>Posted by {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

How would I modify my views.py file to ensure I get the first and last name of the user responsible for the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(active=True)   
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h2><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <p>{{ post.excerpt|truncatewords:30 }}</p>
    <p>Posted by {{ post.user.first_name }} {{ post.user.last_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Many thanks Alp! I was over thinking it. I imagined doing for loops and all sorts of crazy voodoo.

Comment: you are welcome. i am new to django too, started last week. see my current (unanswered) questions if you are interested :)

Comment: I will have a flick through your questions and see if I can help out. :)

Comment: In addition to this answer, look into `select_related` to prevent an extra database query per post to get the user table information.

Answer (score 1):

Use "post.user" in your template instead of just "user".

```
{{ post.user.first_name }} {{ post.user.last_name }}
```

"user" is the current logged-in user.

If you use RequestContext & added auth to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, user is equal to request.user. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates

Comment: he assigns `user` to be the `User` with pk=1. besides, isn't `request.user` the logged-in user?

Comment: `request.user` and `user` are equivalent in templates

Comment: If you use RequestContext & added auth to yout TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, user is equal to request.user. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates

I was confused by this before since I didn't know user is always available.

Comment: ch3ka: Yes. Are you responsible for the downvote? I'm not taking offense. My answer is pretty much the same as the correct answer.

Comment: I am. sorry, your answer seemed to be pointing in the wrong direction. mind to clarify that in the answer? I'll remove the downvote then.

Comment: I just added an explanation on why user is the same as request.user.